# Character-based transitions (part of a lexer)

Tags: parsing, reinventing-the-wheel, rust, state-machine

As part of my prep for the Code Review [community-challenge](/questions/tagged/community-challenge) (which looks like it will be *Write your own programming language*), I've been working on an LL(1) lexer generator in Rust.

Yes, lexer generators exist already, and full-on lexer/parser generators as well. My time might've been better spent building a Rust target for ANTLR (as that's the tool I know best already).

Right now though, I'm just looking at my model for transitions in the finite automaton that gets built up to turn the regex-ish into an actual lexer. Because the lexer generator I'm building is Unicode-first, a simple table of input symbols would be `0x110000` characters wide. That's pretty much an instant veto. Instead, I'm using a enum that allows globbing of sets of characters into one transition:

```
#[derive(Debug, Clone, Copy, Hash, PartialEq, Eq, PartialOrd, Ord)]
pub enum Transition {
    Empty,
    Character(char),
    Range(char, char),
}
```

In the future, it will also support specifying blocks of characters by Unicode properties.

For the NFA model, just using the character and/or ranges specified by the user is fine; the ambiguity is inbuilt into the model anyway. But to make a lexer, I have to disambiguate different transitions, such that only one can be chosen at any time.

As a simple example, take the simple grammar:

```
If: "if" ;
Ident: [[:alpha:]][[:alnum:]]* ;
```

The NFA is trivial:

[image: digraph nfa { rankdir=LR; node [shape = doublecircle]; If Ident; node [shape = circle]; Entry -> 1 [ label = "'i'" ]; 1 -> If [ label = "'f'" ]; Entry -> Ident [ label = "[:alpha:]" ]; Ident -> Ident [ label = "[:alnum:]" ]; }]

But the DFA requires allowing for the `'i'` and `'f'` transitions being subsets of the transitions that the rule `Ident` follows.

[image: digraph dfa { rankdir=LR; node [shape = doublecircle]; If Ident; node [shape = circle]; Entry -> 1 [ label = "'i'" ]; 1 -> If [ label = "'f'" ]; 1 -> Ident [ label = "[:alnum:] - 'f'" ]; If -> Ident [ label = "[:alnum:]" ]; Entry -> Ident [ label = "[:alpha:] - 'i'" ]; Ident -> Ident [ label = "[:alnum:]" ]; }]

To that end, and the main point of asking this review, I have a function `Transition::disambiguate` which takes two transitions and returns a set of transitions that cover all combinations of those two transitions. So `disambiguate( 'a'..='e', 'c' )` returns the set `{ 'a'..='b', 'c', 'd'..='e' }`.

### Enough of the theory, let's see the code

```
use std::{char, fmt};
use std::cmp::{max, min};

#[derive(Debug, Clone, Copy, Hash, PartialEq, Eq, PartialOrd, Ord)]
pub enum Transition {
    Empty,
    Character(char),
    Range(char, char),
}

impl Transition {
    pub fn overlaps(&self, other: &Transition) -> bool {
        match (*self, *other) {
            (Transition::Empty, Transition::Empty) => true,
            (Transition::Empty, _) | (_, Transition::Empty) => false,
            (Transition::Character(x), Transition::Character(y)) => x == y,
            (Transition::Range(lo, hi), Transition::Character(c)) |
            (Transition::Character(c), Transition::Range(lo, hi)) => lo <= c && c <= hi,
            (Transition::Range(lo1, hi1), Transition::Range(lo2, hi2)) => hi1 >= lo2 || lo1 <= hi2,
        }
    }
}

impl From<(char, char)> for Transition {
    fn from(pair: (char, char)) -> Transition {
        let (lo, hi) = pair;
        if lo == hi {
            Transition::Character(hi)
        } else {
            Transition::Range(lo, hi)
        }
    }
}

impl From<char> for Transition {
    fn from(char: char) -> Transition {
        Transition::Character(char)
    }
}

// TODO: move
fn before(c: char) -> char {
    if c as u32 == 0 {
        panic!("Tried to get character before '\\0'")
    }
    let mut point = c as u32 - 1;
    if point == 0xDFFF {
        point = 0xD800 - 1;
    }
    char::from_u32(point).expect("Unexpected surrogate codepoint")
}

// TODO: move
fn after(c: char) -> char {
    if c == char::MAX {
        panic!("Tried to get character after char::MAX")
    }
    let mut point = c as u32 + 1;
    if point == 0xD800 {
        point = 0xDFFF + 1;
    }
    char::from_u32(point).expect("Unexpected surrogate codepoint")
}

impl Transition {
    pub fn disambiguate(lhs: Transition, rhs: Transition) -> Vec<Transition> {
        if !Transition::overlaps(&lhs, &rhs) {
            return vec![lhs, rhs];
        }

        if lhs == rhs {
            return vec![lhs];
        }

        match (lhs, rhs) {
            (Transition::Character(_), Transition::Character(_)) |
            (Transition::Empty, _) |
            (_, Transition::Empty) => unreachable!(),
            (Transition::Range(lo, hi), Transition::Character(c)) |
            (Transition::Character(c), Transition::Range(lo, hi)) => {
                assert!(lo <= c && c <= hi);
                if lo == c {
                    vec![Transition::from(c), Transition::from((after(c), hi))]
                } else if c == hi {
                    vec![Transition::from((lo, before(c))), Transition::from(c)]
                } else {
                    assert!(lo < c && c < hi);
                    vec![
                        Transition::from((lo, before(c))),
                        Transition::from(c),
                        Transition::from((after(c), hi)),
                    ]
                }
            },
            (Transition::Range(lo1, hi1), Transition::Range(lo2, hi2)) => {
                assert!((lo2 <= lo1 && lo1 <= hi2) || (lo1 <= lo2 && lo2 <= hi1));
                let points = [
                    min(lo1, lo2),
                    max(lo1, lo2),
                    min(hi1, hi2),
                    max(hi1, hi2),
                ];
                vec![
                    Transition::from((points[0], before(points[1]))),
                    Transition::from((points[1], points[2])),
                    Transition::from((after(points[2]), points[3])),
                ]
            },
        }
    }
}

impl fmt::Display for Transition {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter) -> fmt::Result {
        match *self {
            Transition::Empty => write!(f, "ε"),
            Transition::Character(c) => write!(f, "{:?}", c),
            Transition::Range(low, high) => write!(f, "{:?}..={:?}", low, high),
        }
    }
}

#[cfg(test)]
#[cfg_attr(rustfmt, rustfmt_skip)]
mod test {
    use super::Transition;
    #[test]
    fn disambiguate_char_range() {
        assert_eq!(
            Transition::disambiguate(
                Transition::Character('c'),
                Transition::Range('a', 'e'),
            ),
            vec![
                Transition::Range('a', 'b'),
                Transition::Character('c'),
                Transition::Range('d', 'e'),
            ]
        );
        assert_eq!(
            Transition::disambiguate(
                Transition::Character('a'),
                Transition::Range('a', 'b'),
            ),
            vec![
                Transition::Character('a'),
                Transition::Character('b'),
            ]
        );
        assert_eq!(
            Transition::disambiguate(
                Transition::Character('b'),
                Transition::Range('a', 'b'),
            ),
            vec![
                Transition::Character('a'),
                Transition::Character('b'),
            ]
        );
        assert_eq!(
            Transition::disambiguate(
                Transition::Character('a'),
                Transition::Range('a', 'c'),
            ),
            vec![
                Transition::Character('a'),
                Transition::Range('b', 'c'),
            ]
        );
        assert_eq!(
            Transition::disambiguate(
                Transition::Character('c'),
                Transition::Range('a', 'c'),
            ),
            vec![
                Transition::Range('a', 'b'),
                Transition::Character('c'),
            ]
        )
    }

    #[test]
    fn disambiguate_range_range() {
        assert_eq!(
            Transition::disambiguate(
                Transition::Range('a', 'c'),
                Transition::Range('c', 'e'),
            ),
            vec![
                Transition::Range('a', 'b'),
                Transition::Character('c'),
                Transition::Range('d', 'e'),
            ]
        );
        assert_eq!(
            Transition::disambiguate(
                Transition::Range('a', 'b'),
                Transition::Range('b', 'c'),
            ),
            vec![
                Transition::Character('a'),
                Transition::Character('b'),
                Transition::Character('c'),
            ]
        );
        assert_eq!(
            Transition::disambiguate(
                Transition::Range('a', 'c'),
                Transition::Range('c', 'd'),
            ),
            vec![
                Transition::Range('a', 'b'),
                Transition::Character('c'),
                Transition::Character('d'),
            ]
        );
        assert_eq!(
            Transition::disambiguate(
                Transition::Range('a', 'b'),
                Transition::Range('b', 'd'),
            ),
            vec![
                Transition::Character('a'),
                Transition::Character('b'),
                Transition::Range('c', 'd'),
            ]
        );
        assert_eq!(
            Transition::disambiguate(
                Transition::Range('a', 'e'),
                Transition::Range('b', 'd'),
            ),
            vec![
                Transition::Character('a'),
                Transition::Range('b', 'd'),
                Transition::Character('e'),
            ]
        );
        assert_eq!(
            Transition::disambiguate(
                Transition::Range('a', 'c'),
                Transition::Range('b', 'd'),
            ),
            vec![
                Transition::Character('a'),
                Transition::Range('b', 'c'),
                Transition::Character('d'),
            ]
        )
    }
}
```

I have cut down `fn disambiguate` a *lot* from its first iteration, and all of the tests I added continue to pass. I'm just afraid that I may be missing some corner cases in my tests, and that reading that mess of a match isn't the easiest task. `unreachable!()` is also a (weak) smell, since your code could potentially be structured such that you don't need it.

`Transition::Range` is an inclusive range and constructing a decreasing or size one range is an error in use.

Oh, and `rustfmt.toml`:

```toml
fn_single_line = true
match_block_trailing_comma = true
wrap_match_arms = false
```

Comment: The graph images were made using [Webgraphvis](http://webgraphviz.com/).

Comment: Haven't looked through your code really, but are there really cases where you'd want `iffoo` to be two separate tokens? I know for JS for instance, keyword processing doesn't happen until after the `if` token has been parsed as a general identifier.

Comment: @loganfsmyth If you look at the DFA you'll see that `iffoo` would parse as an Ident in that trivial example. But that was more an example of the kind of cases that mean this disambiguation is required. (The final product may use a rule for ident-like keywords instead of having them be a separate lexer path; this example, again, was chosen for simplicity. This is just the transition model anyway.)